# Monogame - SpriteBatch.DrawString() won't work

Tags: c#, monogame, text

Here is my `Game1.Draw()` method (Constants.HeroLayerDepth is equal to 1):

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.AntiqueWhite);

        //  gameEngine.DrawEverything(spriteBatch, camera);
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.DrawString(defaultFont, "Test Field", new Vector2(0, 0),
            Color.Black, 0, new Vector2(0, 0), 0f, SpriteEffects.None, Constants.HeroLayerDepth);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Although I am calling DrawString(), I only see this after running the code:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: ok, lets check your spriteFont ( i think is defaultFont ), did you add it correctly to pipeline tool?, here you can see a good example:
http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-drawing-text-with-spritefonts

Comment: I have added my sprite font according to this tutorial. The font name is Arial and it used to work, it just doesn’t now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(defaultFont, "Test Field", new Vector2(0, 0),
        Color.Black, 0, new Vector2(0, 0), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, Constants.HeroLayerDepth);
```

The problem is the ‘scale’ parameter: it is set to zero in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sry, cant make comments. But is the `base.Draw(gameTime);` pheraps going to another overiding class that may make a `GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.AntiqueWhite);`?

*(oh, this was an old question, guess you've moved along by now)*

Comment: Yeah, I have fixed this bug. The problem was actually somewhere in the arguments, but I forgot where